# Performance do programa pela ordem de carregamento de módulos

Tags: python, python-3.x, desempenho

Alguém saberia me dizer se existe uma diferença relevante na performance de um programa (no caso, feito em Python) ao importar todos os módulos a serem utilizados desde o início do código em vez de importá-los apenas no momento (linha) que forem ser usados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade, não existe uma resposta absoluta, e depende do perfil da sua apliação. Na grande maioria das vezes é melhor fazer a importação no início do módulo - até por uma convenção de estilo de uso da linguagem.

Um módulo em Python, uma vez importado em um programa em execução, nao é mais lido do disco ou re-compilado.

No entanto, na primeira vez que ele é importado, pode sim haver alguma demora ao executar o seu código e inicializar os estados internos. Em geral, não é interessante que um programa, uma vez que esteja em execução fique dando "soquinhos" - por exemplo - ao atender uma requisição específica de rede, em um código que ainda não rodou desde que o servidor subiu, se o import estiver dentro da função, a primeira requisição pode demorar um tempo muito maior do que as demais.

Então, na maior parte das vezes, para se evitar esse efeito, e também por uma convenção de estilo, os import são colocados todos no início de um módulo. Mas, há casos em que justamente o contrário é desejado - é preferível que um módulo seja inicializado mais rápido e uma eventual demora na inicialização de uma dependencia aconteça só em tempo de execução quando (e se) um trecho específico for necessário. Um exemplo desse caso é a inicialização do prórpio Python - é muito importante que o tempo que a linguagem em si leva para estar pronta para começar a processar o código do programa que vai executar seja o mais curto possível, então tudo o que não é estritamente necessário para a linguagem funcionar tem sua importação adiada.

E por fim, há casos de dependência circular entre módulos, em que sim, é melhor de propósito colocar uma importação dentro de uma função ou método, a fim de que ela só ocorra depois que o outro módulo já tenha sido 100% inicializado. Um exemplo de estrutura de aplicação em que essa ordem é importante é em aplicativos Flask com SqlAlchemy, em que a própria declaração das classes de modelos de dados depende da aplicação flask e o engine do SQLAlchemy já terem sido inicializados. Nesse caso os módulos contendo esses modelos não podem ser importados antes do código que faz essa inicialização.Esse último caso não tem a ver com performance, e sim, com a organização lógica da aplicação.

Comment: Qual opção (tudo no início ou conforme etapa de execução) você recomendaria para um algoritmo de machine learning?

Comment: Tudo no início, sem dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe diferença relevante de desempenho na performance neste caso.

Há algumas diferenças funcionais. Por exemplo, se o módulo *a* usa o módulo *b* e o módulo *b* usa o módulo *a*, ao usar importações no início do código, você vai ter um erro devido às importações cíclicas. Se você colocar tais importações apenas no momento que for usá-las, não haverá erro.